# How can I select rows from a hierarchical query with the lowest level?

Tags: oracle

*Apologies for the cross-post from StackExchange DBA - I wasn't sure which site was best for this question.*

I have a hierarchical query in Oracle 11gR2 that returns something like this:

- Parent (Level 1)

  - Child (Level 2)

    - Grandchild (Level 3)
  - Child (Level 2)

    - Grandchild (Level 3)
    - Grandchild (Level 3)
  - Child (Level 2)

The query I would like to write should get all the rows matching some predicate, for the minimum level; i.e. nearest the parent. For example, if one of the child rows matches the predicate, it should return just that row, irrespective of whether any grandchild rows match. If multiple child rows match, it should return all of them, again irrespective of grandchild rows. If no child rows match, it should return any grandchild rows that match, etc. (In the real system I have a lot more than three levels, and lots more rows per level.)

I assume this is possible with analytic functions, but I'm not sure which one to use, or how to integrate it into my query. I've seen similar problems solved using `min (level) keep (dense_rank last order by level)`, but that doesn't seem to do quite what I want.